# Sass Error deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am deploying to Heroku and am facing this error. This error does not surface on my local machine.

I haven't found much googling this issue. Can anybody provide pointers to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Regards,
SB

ERROR TRACE-----------------------------

```
undefined method `declare' for Sass::Script::Functions:Module
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass/sass_functions.rb:8:in `<module:Functions>'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass/sass_functions.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:5:in `require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:5:in `load!'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass.rb:74:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/Rakefile:5:in `require'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
       /tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `load'
       vendor/bundle/bin/rake:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try adding `require 'sass'` to your `config.ru` file.

Comment: @CWitty tried it. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
/tmp/build_da95c3d7-39ce-4b2e-9cdd-0fa67ee25910/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/lib/bootstrap-sass/sass_functions.rb:8:in `<module:Functions>'
```

That's your error, and [here's the file](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/bootstrap-sass/sass_functions.rb):

```
require 'sass'

module Sass
  module Script
    module Functions
      # LARS: Snatched from compass - 2011-11-29 - used for gradients in IE6-9
      # returns an IE hex string for a color with an alpha channel
      # suitable for passing to IE filters.
      def ie_hex_str(color)
        assert_type color, :Color
        alpha = (color.alpha * 255).round
        alphastr = alpha.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0')
        Sass::Script::String.new("##{alphastr}#{color.send(:hex_str)[1..-1]}".upcase)
      end
      declare :ie_hex_str, [:color]
    end
  end
end
```

You should try precompiling your assets locally & seeing what errors come back. Apart from that, you'll have to Google this error & file for the answers :)

Comment: I tried pre-compiling assets locally but it did not help. Eventually I removed the gem "bootstrap-sass", ">= 2.0.1" and it worked fine.